# Which smartwatches have autorestart timers?

Tags: smart-watches

Please advise of

1. any smartwatches that have **timers** that **autorestart features** namely where dismiss and reset are in one swipe and swipes are required

or

2. how certain smartwatch **alarms** can achieve such.

Context:

I had previously asked about [Pomodoro](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30949/countdown-timer-or-pomodoro-for-android-that-is-automatically-restarted-but-asks/39551#39551) or [HIIT](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31167/hiit-timer-variant-for-android) timer variants that have an autoreset feature unlike timer but still asked to be dismissed. Do Android smartwatches have something like what [I Can't Wake Up](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kog.alarmclock&hl=en) has?

Example:

Let's say it is 11:59am. I want to be reminded of the time at 12:05pm and then be reminded every 5 minutes.

Currently, I am using my phone.

So either I set a timer for 5 minutes when it's 12pm or I set an alarm to ring at 12:05pm. If timer: I want an option to autorestart after dismiss (so far I haven't found any). If alarm: I want an option to snooze not so easily (with I Can't Wake Up, I can make it so that I have to slide up to snooze or slide down to dismiss).

But it's a hassle to get my phone out every time wherein sometimes I have to first unlock the phone first snoozing the alarm (I Can't Wake Up has 'Quit Block', but I have yet to try this).

I'm hoping some smartwatch has the ability to go off at 12:05pm or 5 minutes after I set the timer (which would be around 12pm) so that I just have to swipe my watch instead of taking out my phone.

I haven't been able to find such features for any smartwatch, but I may be using wrong keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your smartwatch alarm to snooze every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The [Xiaomi mi band 2](http://www.mi.com/in/miband2/) supports alarms that can be snoozed for 10 minutes. When an alarm goes off (lets say 12.00 PM), a tap on the band snoozes it for 10 minutes. A long press on the band stops and dismisses the alarm.

Comment: All smartwatches have alarms which we can use to snooze instead of using timers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, actually what I understood, you want something like snooze alarm and also the harder to stop the alarm, the better. I mean like you said about that "I Can't Wake Up" apps.

The one thing that cross my mind is Pebble SmartWatch. Maybe you can take a look at the product and read [review here](https://wearvs.com/review/pebble-time-steel). But the thing is, you can utilize the Gentle Wake app which can be remarkably personalized.

https://apps.getpebble.com/en_US/application/546047390db50db6e100002b?dev_settings=true&native=false

Furthermore, there is also an alternative known as Konami Code that you could select to be able to stop the alarm vibrations once the alarm goes off.You need to push the side buttons in the exact order shown on the watch so that you can stop the alarm, which avoids you from effortlessly switching off the alarm when you find yourself not fully awake. Beside, additionally, it has a "get out of bed" setting which will switch off the alarm as soon as it sees you have walked around.